# calculus fine the position of the object at time t

Tags: calculus

Suppose an object is moving with acceleration $a(t)=\sin t+3t$, and at time $0$ the velocity $v(0)=0$ and the position $s(0)=2$.
Find the position of the object at time $t$.

Comment: Integrate two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
$$v(t) = \int v'(t)dt = \int a(t)dt = \int\left(\sin t+3t\right)dt$$
$$\Rightarrow v(t) = -\cos t + \frac{3t^2}{2} + C$$
Since v(0) = 0, then:
$$v(0) = -\cos 0+C =0 \Longrightarrow C = 1 $$

Also since $$s(t) = \int v(t)dt = \int \left(-\cos t + \frac{3t^2}{2} + 1\right)dt \text{ and } s(0) = 2 $$

You are able to find out the position function $s(t)$.